# How do I run the Log4j2-Kafka-Appender in OSGi

Tags: java, apache-kafka, osgi, log4j2, equinox

Can anyone please tell me how to run the Log4j2-Kafka-Appender in an OSGi environment? The Console- and File-Appenders are running just fine. But when I add a Kafka-Appender as described in the docs I get the following error.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.factoris.util.logging.internal.Activator.start() of bundle com.factoris.util.logging2.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:795)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<clinit>(ProducerConfig.java:305)
    at com.factoris.util.logging.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.java:364)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.newKafkaProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka.KafkaManager.startup(KafkaManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka.KafkaAppender.start(KafkaAppender.java:175)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:266)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs.<clinit>(CommonClientConfigs.java:32)
    ... 18 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<clinit>(ProducerConfig.java:305)
    at com.factoris.util.logging.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.java:364)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.newKafkaProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka.KafkaManager.startup(KafkaManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka.KafkaAppender.start(KafkaAppender.java:175)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:266)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs.<clinit>(CommonClientConfigs.java:32)
    ... 18 more
```

I found the following bug on the Log4j2 Bugtracker which seem to be this error but I don't know how to implement the proposed solution in an OSGi-Environment.

https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2375

**UPDATE 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

      ...
  <Appenders>
    <Kafka name="Kafka" topic="log-test">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%date %message"/>
        <Property name="bootstrap.servers">localhost:9092</Property>
    </Kafka>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="Kafka"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO" /> <!-- avoid recursive logging -->
  </Loggers>
```

Comment: Can you please show your logging configuration?

Comment: I'm just using the standard configuration from the docs. See mee update above.